# Avoid 404 page override

Tags: python, django

I 'm using django-lfs with default django-app.Its appear django-lfs override 404 default template. How to avoid this process

Answer (score 0):

Within the templates folder, there is should be a `404.html`. Remove that, and django defaults to the standard 404 page!

Comment: I already put 404.html to django default templates folder. The File you suggest to remove is 404.html in lfs lib dir ?

Comment: There have another way to do this without remove 404.html from lfstheme?